# Decimal analogue to boolean AND operator?

Tags: functions, summation, boolean-algebra, binary

I am looking for a way of expressing something like:

$\sum{a_k} \sum{b_k}, \, a_k \in \mathbb{R}, \, b_k \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1}$

with the caveat that I would like the result to be negative in the case in which $\sum{a_k} < 0$ and $\sum{b_k} < 0$ .

In summary, I would like a function/operator that behaves like multiplication sans the case where `- * - = +`  but rather when both are negative then I expect a negative answer.

I can see a way of doing this with binary numbers represented in sign-magnitude, by doing the usual multiplication of the magnitude bits and the NAND of the sign bits. However, I am failing in finding a way of extending this to decimal numbers.

Is there some way I could add something to $(1)$ so it behaves like this?

Comment: Please edit your question. This has nothing to do with decimal. Calling the sums $A,\,B$, you want a function of them that is $\pm AB$, and is negative whenever at least one of $A,\,B$ is negative. Equivalently, it's $\pm|AB|$, and only takes the $+$ sign when $A,\,B$ are both positive. You should be able to solve it now in terms of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this not having anything to do with decimal? I had thought of using the sign function, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Write a table of values of $\operatorname{sgn}A,\,\operatorname{sgn}B,\,\operatorname{sgn}AB$, each equal to a number $\pm1$ rather than just a $\pm$ sign. You should spot a concise characterization.

Comment: When $sgn(A)=-1$ and $sgn(B)=-1$, $sgn(AB)=1$, I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the sign of the not-quite-product you want, rather than the usual definition of $AB$.